# Selenium webdriver. How to install chrome extension when run test via selenium grid?

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I try to run test of my chrome extension locally.

I have selenium-server (v.3.141.59).

I have chromedriver (v.2.44)

I have chrome browser (v.70.0.3538.110)

And selenium-webdriver npm package (v.^4.0.0-alpha.1)

My NodeJs code successfully creating new chrome session

```
        this._driver = new Builder()
          .forBrowser('chrome')
          .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
          .setChromeOptions(new ChromeOptions()
            .addExtensions(config.extensionPath)
            //.addExtensions(buffer.toString('base64'))
            //.addArguments(`--load-extension=c:\path\to\extension`)
        .build();
```

BUT

1) When I run selenium-server as standalone server, my extension successfully installed and it's OK

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role standalone
```

2) When I run selenium-server as hub and another instance of selenium-server as node new chrome session created without installed extension.

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role hub

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path\to\chromedriver -jar selenium-server.jar -port 4445 -hub http://localhost:4444 -role node -browser browserName=chrome
```

Any of commented variants of loading extension gives same result.

Is there any differences between node and standalone types of running (in context of extension loading)?
Or where my mistake?

I will be glad for any help!

Comment: hey, did you figure out the solution? facing the same issue

Comment: It is sad, but I don't... If you'll find the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution recently, it's quite hacky.
There was a thread about this in selenium's github but can't recall it at the moment. The solution is to pass the chrome options capabilities key as 'goog:chromeOptions' when using remote hub.

example:

```
setup() {
    const options = new Options();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");

    options.addExtensions(this.encode(*extension*.crx'));


    const caps = new Capabilities();
    caps.set("browserName", 'chrome');

    //seems like neccessary hack for js bindings
    caps.set('goog:chromeOptions', options['options_']);

    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .withCapabilities(caps)
        .usingServer(*url*)
        .build(); 
}

encode(file) {
    var stream = require('fs').readFileSync(file);
    return Buffer.from(stream).toString('base64');
}
```

Comment: (node:16426) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Options is not a constructor. How to fix?

Comment: same here. I had added it `const { Builder, By, Key, until, Options, Capabilities } = require("selenium-webdriver");` but it seems it's not that easy...